How to Keep a Product's Brilliance with a White Background (No HDRI)?
I'm trying to maintain the brilliance of a product with 0.050 roughness while avoiding HDRI environments. My goal is to use a white background with minimal reflections, preserving the product's glossy appearance.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far :
Attempt 1 : Standard White Background
I used a standard white background (either on the ground or in the back), but the problem is that it reflects all over the product, giving it a "matte" appearance and ruining the brilliance I'm trying to preserve.
Example :

As you can see, the square background and its corners reflect onto the product, which dulls the glossy effect I'm aiming for.
Attempt 2 : Emission Planes with Adjusted Ray Visibility
I removed the white background and added planes with emission shaders. In the Ray Visibility settings (right-hand panel), I disabled Diffuse and Glossy.
This approach produced results closer to what I’m looking for, but the outcome still looks somewhat harsh or "flashy":

Ideal Outcome Using HDRI
When using HDRI environments, the result is much smoother and closer to my desired look :

However, HDRIs introduce multiple reflections (like windows, lights, or clouds), making it hard to reuse the product in a white background setup. This is why I prefer avoiding HDRIs altogether.
My Question :
How can I achieve the right balance of lighting to keep the product's brilliance with a white background while avoiding unwanted reflections and preserving the smoothness that HDRIs provide?
Any advice or best practices for setting up the lighting would be greatly appreciated!

You can't have gorgeous reflections if the world shader is just plain white. You need an actual environment with details to get detailed reflections. If you are using Cycles, you can use a Light Path > Is Camera Ray to have 2 shaders in one : one is used for reflections, one is used only to display the background (but doesn't affect reflections and such). Did you try that ?

I haven't tried that, is this how you connect it ? :
https://ibb.co/gSk9TGX

Close but no. Is Camera Ray should be the factor of the Mix Shader. Then, you want to have 2 Background connected to it, one is white, one is the HDRI. Alternatively, you can do the same process with a Mix Color (again with 2 colors connected), then use it on a unique Background. Depends if you want to have 2 emission strength or only one. Sorry for not writing a full answer, hope it helps nontheless.

To give you a few examples for what @Lutzi told you about, if you want to use an HDRI for lighting and reflections but do not want to see it in the background, you can always use two different Background nodes and combine them in a Mix Shader, where you can take the Light Path > Is Camera Ray as mix factor. The HDRI should then be the first shader input, the simple color the second input:

This way you can always change the color of the background without any effect on the lighting and reflections in the scene, and as Lutzi mentioned, this method is good if you also want to have different Strength settings for both backgrounds, like the HDRI using default 1, the white background I've set to 15 to make sure it's white even with color management, while the black is set to 0:

Or another way if you do not need different emission strengths for the different backgrounds, you can use just a single Background node and use the Is Camera Ray as mix factor in a Mix Color node instead, where the HDRI will be the first color and you choose a second color for the visible background:

Another method would be doing it in the Compositor. This way you do not have to work on the world background itself, just use an HDRI and in the Render Properties and enable Film > Transparent so that there is no background visible at all:

Then render the image and go to the Compositor afterwards. There you can use an Alpha Over node to overlay a color with the rendered object. To do this choose a background color in the first Image input and plug the render result into the second Image input:

